# How to select edge rings between two edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, edges, selection-tools

Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> you can select the *Shortest Path* between two selected egdes.
This essentially allows you to select a range edgeloop.
Like so:

[image: edgeloopshortestpath]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> will allow you to select and edge ring like so:

[image: edgering]

But how do I select the shortest path edge ring? Or rather, a range of edge rings between two selected edges.

[image: edgeringrange]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be easier to use another selection tool instead of [*Edge Ring*](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#edge-ring) selection, because it won't take into account specified end of selection.

You can workaround that by selecting faces:

1. Select the shortest path with [*Path Selection*](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#path-selection) in *Face Select* mode.
2. Switch to *Edge Select* mode, and deselect top and bottom edge loops by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and clicking with <kbd>LMB</kbd> on them. "Shortened" edge ring will be the only left selected.

[image: GIF selecting edge ring in specified range]

Comment: Yes that definitely helps! I wonder if there's any add-on that allows for this.

Answer (score 2):

that is already in blender but kinda a hidden option here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fd0APrTJw1lcY_9TPPozra-RLFsyghHm/view?usp=sharing
PD:i couldnt upload as gif lol...

Comment: for the one who can't see the gif, works in blender 2.9x :
in edge mode select first edge than last edge then in the options of "Pick shortest path" select "Face stepping"

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> for a Ring Selection.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> for a Loop Selection.